# How can I consume more than the reserved number of request units with Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have reserved various number of RUs per second for our various collections. I'm trying to optimize this to save money. For each response from Cosmos, we're logging the request charge property to Application Insights. I have one analytics query that returns the average number of request units per second and one that returns the maximum.

```
let start = datetime(2019-01-24 11:00:00);
let end = datetime(2019-01-24 21:00:00);
customMetrics
| where name == 'RequestCharge' and start < timestamp and timestamp < end
| project timestamp, value, Database=tostring(customDimensions['Database']), Collection=tostring(customDimensions['Collection'])
| make-series sum(value) default=0 on timestamp in range(start, end, 1s) by Database, Collection
| mvexpand sum_value to typeof(double), timestamp limit 36000
| summarize avg(sum_value) by Database, Collection
| order by Database asc, Collection asc
```

```
let start = datetime(2019-01-24 11:00:00);
let end = datetime(2019-01-24 21:00:00);
customMetrics
| where name == 'RequestCharge' and start <= timestamp and timestamp <= end
| project timestamp, value, Database=tostring(customDimensions['Database']), Collection=tostring(customDimensions['Collection'])
| summarize sum(value) by Database, Collection, bin(timestamp, 1s)
| summarize arg_max(sum_value, *) by Database, Collection 
| order by Database asc, Collection asc
```

The averages are fairly low but the maxima can be unbelievably high in some cases. An extreme example is a collection with a reservation of 1,000, an average used of 15,59 and a maximum used of 63,341 RUs/s.

My question is: How can this be? Are my queries wrong? Is throttling not working? Or does throttling only work on a longer period of time than a single second? I have checked for request throttling on the Azure Cosmos DB overview dashboard (response code 429), and there was none.

Comment: Without seeing specific queries (and related RU cost), there's really no way to know why it cost so much. Also, it's unclear whether you're saying that a single query cost 63K, or that you somehow consumed 63K in a 1-second period. A 63K cost for a single query seems a bit extreme (though it's quite possible to drive up costs with a malformed spatial query, for instance, with the polygon built in the wrong direction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to answer myself. I found two problems:

1. Application Insights logs an inaccurate timestamp. I added a timestamp as a custom dimension, and within a certain minute I get different seconds in my custom timestamp but the built-in timestamp is one second past the minute for many of these. That is why I got (false) peaks in request charge.
2. We did have throttling. When viewing request throttling in the portal, I have to select a specific database. If I try to view request throttling for all databases, it looks like there is none.